# Getting "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error for UIButton touch events added programmatically

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, unrecognized-selector

I have a UITableView displaying a list of content, and I want each item in the list to have a checkbox that can be marked and unmarked by user touch.  I have created a UIButton for each cell, set it to the cell's accessoryView, and added the target method to be called.

However, I always get the "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error whenever I attempt to click on the checkbox, and I have no idea why.  I looked all over the place to figure out what's causing the error, and made sure my addTarget call and selected method are using proper syntax, but maybe I'm missing something.  What do I need to change to fix this error?

Here is the code for creating the cells:

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        // Set up the cell...
        PFObject *tempMap = [searchResults objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
        cell.textLabel.text = [tempMap objectForKey:@"mapName"];

        // Add checkbox to cell
        UIButton *checkBox = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        checkBox.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
        cell.accessoryView = checkBox;
        checkBox.tag = indexPath.row;
        [checkBox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [checkBox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [checkBox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-pressed.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

        [checkBox addTarget:self action:@selector(checkBoxButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell addSubview:checkBox];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

This is the method that's being called, checkBoxButton:

```
- (void)checkboxButton:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *checkBox = sender;

    if (checkBox.selected)
    {
        [selectedMaps removeObject:[searchResults objectAtIndex:checkBox.tag]];
        NSLog(@"..Map Deselected..");
    }
    else
    {
        [selectedMaps addObject:[searchResults objectAtIndex:checkBox.tag]];
        NSLog(@"..Map Selected..");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're registering the selector `checkBoxButton:` but you're actually implementing `checkboxButton:` (note the difference in capitalization of the first "B").

Comment: AHAHA I'm an idiot!  Thank you for pointing out this extremely obvious error.  I'll probably go ahead and delete the question then.

Comment: @desmondhume, FYI, you can't delete a question once you get an answer for it. Another thing, this is also not suggestable at all (due to this your account may get locked permanently). And thus, better accept the correct answer is the only possible good way. StackOverflow is never comparing between type of questions (idiot/einstein) :)